# Evaluation of the indefinite integral $\int{\frac{\cosh(2x)}{\sinh^2(x) \cosh^2(x)}dx}$

Tags: integration

How to compute $\int{\frac{\cosh(2x)}{\sinh^2(x) \cosh^2(x)}dx}$?

The answer I am provided with is  tgh(x)-ctgh(x) but I have no idea whether this is actually correct and how to get this.

Comment: Did you try differentiating to check?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$$\int{\frac{\cosh(2x)}{\sinh^2(x) \cosh^2(x)}dx}=
\int{\frac{\cosh^2(x)+\sinh^2(x)}{\sinh^2(x) \cosh^2(x)}dx}$$
$$=\int{\left(\frac{1}{\sinh^2(x)}+\frac{1}{\cosh^2(x)}\right)}dx= \tanh(x)-\coth(x) + C$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$\int \frac{\cosh (2x)}{\sinh^2 (x)\cosh^2(x)}\ dx=\int \frac{\frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{2}}{\left(\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}\right)^2}\ dx$$
$$=8\int \frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{(e^{2x}-e^{-2x})^2}\ dx$$
$$=4\int \frac{d(e^{2x}-e^{-2x})}{(e^{2x}-e^{-2x})^2}$$
$$=4\frac{(-1)}{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}+C$$
$$=-\frac{4}{(e^{x}-e^{-x})(e^{x}+e^{-x})}+C$$
$$=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}-\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}+C$$
$$=\color{red}{\tanh (x)-\coth (x)}+C$$

Comment: You could have left it as hyperbolic and integrated directly.